# How to play youtube video in flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to play youtube video in flutter?

I tried two plugins but there were some bugs in them.

**youtube_player** plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player) gives exoPlayer error for some videos & those videos are not played using this plugin (see https://github.com/sarbagyastha/youtube_player/issues/42).

**youtube_player_flutter** plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter) has serious bugs & it cannot be used for now.

Are there any other options?

Comment: Try https://pub.dev/packages/chewie.

Comment: @AndreiCaisim - chewie plugin requires playable video source link. So, It will be required to get direct video source of Youtube video. Also, I need to have video quality change option. That is not supported in chewie.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using video_player (https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)

```
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(VideoApp());

class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VideoAppState createState() => _VideoAppState();
}

class _VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'youtubevideolink')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {
           // do stuff
        });
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: _controller.value.initialized
              ? AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                )
              : Container(),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _controller.value.isPlaying
                  ? _controller.pause()
                  : _controller.play();
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried now, it doesn't work. Update please.

Comment: It doesn't work. You can't play youtube-video directly with the default exoplayer.

Comment: you cannot play YouTube video using video_player plugin.